# Ruby on Rails Outbound Connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My organization wants to close all outbound connections on our server. They asked me to provide them a list of what connections I need open. Here is what I have:

https://rubygems.org

What else is there? I use RVM. So `rvm install 2.1.1` connects to what? Does `bundle install` connect to anything else other than https://rubygems.org?

What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

As found here: http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/questions/83-getting-past-firewalls

> RubyGems connects to rubygems.org and Amazon Cloudfront so you will
>   need to allow access to both sites. The IP addresses of Amazon
>   Cloudfront are not under RubyGems' control.
>
> Additionally, I just wrote:
>
> http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/installing-gems-with-no-network
>
> Which describes how to install gems when the target machine has no
>   network connectivity.